# set/get data in service from controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

Just trying to figure out how some of this works so I want to input a number in a view then have the controller set that data in the service and switch views. Then the controller for the next view should get that number from the same service and eventually pass it to the server.

On my getters/setters in the controller, I get

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

but I don't seem to understand why. I thought I had followed the documentation and suggestions on other answers but I must be missing something small or completely misunderstanding some concept.

**my service**

```
'use strict';

/* Services 
*/

var equipService = angular.module('getEquipService', []);

equipService.factory('GetEquipment', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    equipService.siteId =1147;

    // these first two I thought I did right but...nope
    this.getId = function() {
            return equipService.siteId;
        }
    this.setId = function(siteId) {
              equipService.siteId = siteId;
        }
    return {

    list:  function(id) {
        return $resource('http://example.com/somelist.cfm', {},{            
          query: {method:'POST', params: {id:id}, isArray:true}
    })}
    }}]);
```

**a controller**

```
var peopleController = angular.module('peopleController', []);

peopleController.controller('LoginController', ['GetEquipment', '$scope', '$log', 
    function(GetEquipment, $scope, $log){
        $scope.buttonText = "Clicked";
        $scope.inputId = "";
        $scope.showPeople = function() {

        // here I thought I could set the number entered
        GetEquipment.setId(this.inputId);
            $log.log("Success!");
            $scope.buttonText = "Get Equipment";                 
    };
}]);

peopleController.controller("PeopleController", ['$scope','$rootScope', '$routeParams', 'GetEquipment', '$log',
function($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, GetEquipment, $log) {
    $scope.people = GetEquipment.list(1260);

    $log.log("showEuip: ", $scope.people);
    $log.log("getting id: ", GetEquipment.getId());
}]);
```

Here

```
GetEquipment.setId(this.inputId);
```

is where I get the above mentioned error (one of a couple places).

My understanding is that since I am using my service as a dependency of each controller, I should be able to access it's functions in this way. Not sure if I am defining the functions incorrectly or something else.

I certainly would like to know why what I'm doing isn't working but, if there is a better approach for passing input data, I would be willing to listen.

Comment: Where is the error happening?

Comment: @LucTheRedstoner on `setId()` there at the bottom. Is the way I am calling `controller()` twice like that a problem?

Comment: It seems like the `peopleController` isn't passing the function `GetEquipment` to your function. If you could insert the `peopleController` code into your question, that would help.

Comment: @LucTheRedstoner I'm not sure I understand which is probably part of the problem ;) But I updated with what is in the `controllers.js`. `'LoginController'` is what is used for the login screen and from there I expect a button press to call that function there and set the id in the service. Let me know if anything else would be helpful.

Comment: What is in the file that `var peopleController = angular.module('peopleController', []);` is accessing to get the `peopleController`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may be mixing up the `factory()` and `service()` methods in angular. Here is how you could implement your `GetEquipment` service using either of the aproaches:

using **module.service()**

```
equipService.service('GetEquipment', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    equipService.siteId = 1147;

    // these first two I thought I did right but...nope
    this.getId = function () {
        return equipService.siteId;
    };
    this.setId = function (siteId) {
        equipService.siteId = siteId;
    };
    this.list = function (id) {
        return $resource('http://example.com/somelist.cfm', {}, {
            query: {method: 'POST', params: {id: id}, isArray: true}
        })
    };
}]);
```

using **module.factory()**

```
equipService.factory('GetEquipment', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    equipService.siteId = 1147;

    return {
        getId: function () {
            return equipService.siteId;
        },
        setId: function (siteId) {
            equipService.siteId = siteId;
        },
        list: function (id) {
            return $resource('http://example.com/somelist.cfm', {}, {
                query: {method: 'POST', params: {id: id}, isArray: true}
            })
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do remember reading about the differences but admit I don't fully understand so will read up on that more. However, changing to service instead of factory results in the same errors.

Comment: Are you using my code sample or did you just change factory to service? Notice that my sample is also not returning anything which is important. Basically if you use `service()` then angular will call your function as a constructor. If you use `factory()` angular will use the return value from your function as the service....and yes the overloaded use of the work service gets a little confusing

Comment: heh, I just changed factory to service because everything seemed to be the same. Missed the "not returning" part. Thanks for the answer and the explanation. Got rid of my errors but it isn't using my input, atm. I guess that's a separate issue I will look into. Thanks again!